# Changing the format of the CSV report download from Toggl

Tags: formatting, csv

Can you change which values are included and how they are formatted, when you download a report as a CSV file from Toggl?

I would like to get the duration of the different tasks in a format that numbers can understand as a duration value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change it when downloading. However, you can load it in a spreadsheet or script and change the format of the duration.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [this Python script that fixes the toggl.com CSV for my purposes](http://7bits.nl/blog/2011/10/22/importing-toggl-com-time-entries-csv-in-iwork-numbers), it may be a useful starting point for your needs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import sys
import operator

r = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
rows=[]
for row in r:
        row[5] = "'%s" % row[5]
        row[6] = "'%s" % row[6]
        row[7] = "'%s" % row[7]
        rows.append(row)

rows = [rows[0]] + sorted(
       rows[1:],
       key=operator.itemgetter(5)
)

w = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
for row in rows:
        w.writerow(row)
```

The script may be useful for Excel users too, I have not checked.